# is there a method to expand an operation on a column of dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

exactly I mean :
suppose we have this `pandas.DataFrame`:

[image]

and we want to expand summation on it! **expected result:**

[image]

**Note that** I want to know if there is a method in `pandas` for this purpose or not? and I know that I can write code with for loops and etc. I'm looking for a method or module in `pandas` package for this kind of calculations.
is there a pre-write method for this in `pandas`?

Comment: IIUC, `df.col.cumsum()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `cumsum()` like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col': [2,3,4,5]
})

df.cumsum()
```

Output:

```
    col
0   2
1   5
2   9
3   14
```

Comment: @Vishnudev, OK, do OP question for other thing?!!

Comment: Sorry. Misunderstood :( @Ch3steR

Comment: @Vishnudev Hey vishnu nothing to apologise man. Sorry if it came out as rude. I just wanted to know if you interpreted the question wrong,